# How do you return an array in a procedure back to the main procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, types, return-value

```
    static string readfileName(string[] name)
    {

        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("StudentMarks.txt"))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string ln;

            while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (ln.Length > 4)
                {
                    name[counter] = ln;
                    counter++;

                }
            }

            file.Close();
            return name;
        }
    }
```

This is the procedure I'm currently trying to return the array `name[50]` but the *compile time error* I can't fix states

> "Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string' "

Comment: You didn't add the brackets to the return type. Therefore it's not an array.

Comment: And now I have a debugging error talking about the return line by saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Comment: That's because you're trying to return the 51st element of an array that doesn't have 51 slots. If you declare an array as being of size [50] you can only refer to array[0] thru array[49] when getting at the actual data. I'll make an edit on the end of my answer to explain in more detail a couple of things that will be relevant

Comment: Side note: `file.Close();` is *redundant* and can be safely dropped: `using` will call `file.Dispose()` on leaving its scope.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to. Your main method passed the array to this method, this method filled it. It doesn't need to hand it back because the object pointed to by your 'name` variable is the same object as pointed to by the original variable in the main method; your main method already has all the array data:

```
static void Main(){

  var x = new string[10];

  MyMethod(x);

  Console.Write(x[0]); //prints "Hello"
}

static void MyMethod(string[] y){

  y[0] = "Hello";

}
```

In this demo code above we start out with an array of size 10 that is referred to by a variable x. In memory it looks like:

```
x --refers to--> arraydata
```

When you call MyMethod and pass x in, c# will create another reference y that points to the same data:

```
x --refers to--> arraydata <--refers to-- y
```

Now because both references point to the same area of memory anything that you do with y, will also affect what x sees. You put a string (like I did with Hello) in slot 0, both x and y see it. When MyMethod finishes, the reference y is thrown away, but x survives and sees all the changes you made when working with y

The only thing you can't do is point y itself to another different array object somewhere else in memory. That won't change x. You can't do this:

```
static void MyMethod(string[] y){

    y = new string[20];

}
```

If you do this your useful reference of x and y pointing to the same area of memory:

```
x ---> array10 <--- y
```

Will change to:

```
x ---> array10       y ---> array20
```

And then the whole array20 and the y reference will be thrown away when MyMethod finishes.

The same rule applies if you call a method that supplies you an array:

```
static void MyMethod(string[] y){

    y = File.ReadAllLines("some path"); //this also points y away to a new array made by ReadAllLines

}
```

It doesn't matter how or who makes the new array. Just remember that you can fiddle with the *contents* of an object pointed to by y all you like and the changes will be seen by x, but you can't change out the entire object pointed to by y and hope x will see it

in that case you WOULD have to pass it back when you're done:

```
static string[] MyMethod(string[] y){
  y = new ... 

  return y;
}
```

And the main method would have to capture the change:

```
Main(...){

  string[] x = new string[10];

  string[] result = MyMethod(x);

}
```

---

Now, while I'm giving this mini lesson of "pass by reference" and "pass by value" (which should have been called "pass by original reference" and "pass by copy of reference") it would be useful to note that there *is* a way to change things so MyMethod can swap y out for a whole new object and x will see the change too.

We don't really use it, ever; there is rarely any need to. Just about the only time it's used is in things like `int.Parse`. I'm telling you for completeness if education so that if you encounter it you understand it but you should always prefer a "change the contents but not the whole object" or a "if you make a new object pass it back" approach

By marking the y argument with the ref keyword, c# wont make a copy of the reference when calling the method, it will use the original reference and temporarily allow you to call it y:

```
static void MyMethod(ref string[] y){
    y = new array[20];
}
```

Our diagram:

```
x ---> array10data
```

Temporarily becomes:

```
x a.k.a y ---> array10data
```

So if you point y to a new array, x experiences the change too, because they're the same reference; y is no longer a different reference to the same data

```
x a.k.a y ---> array20data
```

Like I say, don't use it- we always seek to avoid it for various reasons.

---

Now, I said at the start "you don't need to" - by that, and for the reasons above, I meant *you don't need to return anything from this method*

Your method receives the array it shall fill (from the file) as a parameter; it doesn't make a new array anywhere so there isn't any need to return the array when done. It will just put any line longer than 4 chars into an array slot. It could then finish without returning anything and the method that called this method will see the changes it made in the array. This is just like my code, where MyMethod changes slot 0 of the array, MyMethod was declared as `void` so it didn't need to make a return statement , and my Main method god could still see the Hello that I put in the array. In the same vein, your Main method will see all those lines from the file if you make your ReadFileName method (which should perhaps be called FillArray) because it fills the array called `name`

The most useful thing your method could return is actually an integer saying how many lines were read; the array passed in is of a fixed size. You can't resize it because that entails making a new array which won't work for all those reasons I talked about above. If you were to make a new array and return it there wouldn't be any point in passing an array in.

There are thus several ways we could improve this code but to my mind they come down to two:

- don't pass an array in; let this method make a new array and return it. The new array passed back can be exactly sized to fit
- keep with the "pass an array in" idea and return an integer of how many lines were actually read instead

For the second idea (which is the simplest to implement) you have to change the return type to int:

```
static int ReadFileName(string[] name)
```

And you have to return that variable you use to track which slot to put the next thing in, counter. Counter is always 1 greater than the number of things you've stored so:

```
return counter - 1;
```

Your calling method can now look like:

```
string[] fileData = new string[10000]; //needs to be big enough to hold the whole file!
int numberOfLinesRead = ReadFileName(fileData);
```

Can you see now why ReadFileName is a bad name for the method? Calling it FillArrayFromFile would be better. This last line of code doesn't read like a book, it doesn't make sense from a natural language perspective. Why would something that looks like it reads a file name (if that even makes sense) take an array and return an int - calling it ReadFileName makes it sound more like it searches an array for a filename and returns the slot number it was found in. Here ends the "name your methods appropriately 101"

---

So the other idea was to have the Read method make its own array and return it. While we are at it, let's call it ReadFileNamed, and have it take a file path in so it's not hard coded to reading just that one file. And we will have it return an array

```
static string[] ReadFileNamed(string filepath)
      ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   the return type        the argument passed in
```

Make it so the first thing it does is declare an array big enough to hold the file (there are still problems with this idea, but this is programming 101; I'll let them go. Can't fix everything using stuff you haven't been taught yet)

Put this somewhere sensible:

```
string lines = new string[10000];
```

And change all your occurrences of "name" to be "lines" instead - again we name our variables we'll just like we name our methods sensibly

Change the line that reads the fixed filename to use the variable name we pass in..

```
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath))
```

At the end of the method, the only thing left to do is size the array accurately before we return it. For a 49 line file, counter will be 50 so let's make an array that is 49 big and then fill it using a loop (I doubt you've been shown Array.Copy)

```
string[] toReturn = new string[counter-1];

for(int x = 0; x < toReturn.Length; x++)
  toReturn[x] = lines[x];

return toReturn;
```

And now call it like this:

```
string[] fileLines = ReadFileNamed("student marks.txt");
```

Comment: but the whole point of the separate procedure is to read the contents of a txt file (Which im doing twice) so I cant declare values within the code

Comment: That code snippet was just to demonstrate my point, but I'll make an edit to explain more

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to return name[50] and you know that will be populated, why not go with:

```
static string readfileName(string[] name)
    {

        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("StudentMarks.txt"))
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string ln;

            while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (ln.Length > 4)
                {
                    name[counter] = ln;
                    counter++;

                }
            }

            file.Close();
            return name[50];
        }
    }
```

You're getting the error because your method signature indicates that you're going to return a string, but you're defining name as a string[] in the argument. If you simply select a single index of your array in the return statement, you'll only return a string.

Comment: Im confused what you changed here?

Comment: @Switching I simply changed the return statement at the end to specifically pass back name[50] (and thus the string value at index 50) instead of `name`, the argument passed into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to do several thing in one method:

1. Read `"StudentMarks.txt"` file
2. Put top lines into `name` *existing* array (what if you have *too few* lines in the file?)
3. return 50th (magic number!) item

If you insist on such implementation:

```
using System.Linq;

...

static string readfileName(string[] name)
{
    var data = File
      .ReadLines("StudentMarks.txt")
      .Where(line => line.Length > 4)
      .Take(name.Length);

    int counter = 0; 

    foreach (item in data) 
      if (counter < name.Length)
        name[counter++] = item; 

    return name.Length > 50 ? name[50] : "";
}
```

However, I suggest doing all things separately:

```
 // Reading file lines, materialize them into string[] name
 string[] name = File
   .ReadLines("StudentMarks.txt")
   .Where(line => line.Length > 4)
  // .Take(51) // uncomment, if you want at most 51 items
   .ToArray();

 ...

 // 50th item of string[] name if any
 string item50 = name.Length > 50 ? name[50] : "";
```

**Edit:** Splitting *single* record (`name` and `score`) into *different* collections (`name[]` and `score[]`?) often is a bad idea;
the criterium itself (`line.Length > 4`) is dubious as well (what if we have `Lee` - 3 letter name - with `187` score?). 
Let's implement **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine with `2` states (when we read `name` or `score`) and read `(name, score)` pairs:

```
    var data = File
      .ReadLines("StudentMarks.txt")
      .Select(line => line.Trim())
      .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line));

    List<(string name, int score)> namesAndScores = new List<(string name, int score)>();

    string currentName = null;

    foreach (string item in data) {
      if (null == currentName)
        currentName = item;
      else {
        namesAndScores.Add((currentName, int.Parse(item)));

        currentName = null;
      }
    }
```

Now it's easy to deal with `namesAndScores`:

```
  // 25th student and his/her score:
  if (namesAndScores.Count > 25)
    Console.Write($"{namesAndScores[25].name} achieve {namesAndScores[25].score}");
```

Comment: its basically in the txt file I have student names and then below them on a separate line their score (out of 200), I'm trying to separate the names from the scores by using the 'If (ln.Length > 4)' Line as obviously a full name will be greater than 4 characters long, then at the end I'm attempting to return an array containing only the names (there's meant to be a maximum of 50 names in the txt file). This is my first year properly coding in C# and I'm trying to learn about reading and writing to files as well as arrays through the internet.

Comment: @Switching: I doubt if `(ln.Length > 4)` is a good criterium to separate names and scores: what if you have `Lee 150` record? Technically, you can check if `ln` is *all digits* for score: `if (ln.Trim().Any(c => c < '0' || c > '9')) {/*ln is a name*/}` but the very idea of *splitting* and probably then combining names and scores looks suspicious. I suggest implementing FSM and read combination of `name` and `score`; please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your method to return a `string`, yet the code inside is returning `name`, which is a `string[]`. If you want it to return a `string[]`, then change the signature to specify that:

```
static string[] ReadFileName(string[] name)
```

However, since your method is only populating the array that was passed in, it's not really necessary to return the array, since the caller already has a reference to the array we're modifying (they passed it to our method in the first place).

**There is a potential problem here, though**
We're expecting the caller to pass us an array of the appropriate length to hold all the valid lines from the file, yet that number is unknown until we read the file. We could return an array of the size they specified with either empty indexes at the end if it was too big, or incomplete data if it was too small, but instead we should probably just return them a *new* array, and not require them to pass one to us.

Note that it's easier to use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`, since lists don't require any knowledge of their size at instantiation (they can grow dynamically). Also, we no longer need a `counter` variable (since we're using the `Add` method of the list to add new items), and we can remove the `file.Close()` call since the `using` block will call that automatically (one of the cool things about them):

```
static string[] ReadFileName()
{
    List<string> validLines = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("StudentMarks.txt"))
    {
        string ln;

        while ((ln = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (ln.Length > 4)
            {
                validLines.Add(ln);
            }
        }
    }

    return validLines.ToArray();
}
```

And we can simplify the code even more if we use some static methods of the `System.IO.File` class:

```
static string[] ReadFileName()
{
    return File.ReadLines("StudentMarks.txt").Where(line => line.Length > 4).ToArray();
}
```

We could also make the method a little more robust by allowing the caller to specify the file name as well as the minimum line length requirement:

```
static string[] ReadFileName(string fileName, int minLineLength)
{
    return File.ReadLines(fileName)
        .Where(line => line.Length >= minLineLength).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: No need in `ReadAllLines`; `ReadLines` will be enough